# Layout CSS Panel

Tags: css

I have a HTML page that needs to take up the full height and width of the screen. In short, I'm trying to make it look like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------+
|             |                                         |
| HELLO!      |  MAIN CONTENT WILL GO HERE              |
|             |                                         |
| +---------+ |                                         |
| | nav 1   | |                                         |
| | nav 2   | |                                         |
| | nav 3   | |                                         |
| |         | |                                         |
| |         | |                                         |
| |         | |                                         |
| +---------+ |                                         | 
|             |                                         |
|             |                                         |
| Footer Text |                                         |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

My problem is , I can't get the Footer Text to align against the bottom. At the same time, I can't get the nav 1... navx items to fill the remaining space between the HELLO text and the footer text. Basically, I just need the nav area to fill all remaining space. If there are more items then space, I want to show a scroll bar. Currently, I'm trying the following (as shown in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83czN/)):

```
<div style='height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; background-color:silver;'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <div class="row">HELLO!</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <div style="overflow-y:scroll;">
                      <ul class="side-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                      </ul>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">Footer Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="small-8 columns">
            MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the Fiddle shows, the nav are doesn't take up all of the remaining space. I feel I should communicate that the JSFiddle uses Zurb Foundation. However, I am ***not*** set on using Zurb Foundation. So if there is a pure CSS approach, I'm perfectly content with that as an option. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small patch for your code containing the code below:

```
.small-4 .row {
    display:table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83czN/1/